# Read and Write from serial port in java without listener event

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, inputstream

I want to read bytes from the serial port and write to it sequentially.Is there any way i can read and write from/to the serial port by creating two separate functions for read and write in java?.I wrote a program but here,serialPort.getInputStream() is giving a null pointer exception even after opening the desired COM port.

This is my code

```
        package PhyCom;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.TooManyListenersException;
import javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier;
import javax.comm.PortInUseException;
import javax.comm.SerialPort;
import javax.comm.SerialPortEvent;
import javax.comm.SerialPortEventListener;
import javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;




public class COMConnect_DLMS
{ 
   public static InputStream inputStream;
   public static OutputStream outputStream;  
   SerialPort serialPort;  
   public long baudRate=19200;
   public int dataBits=SerialPort.DATABITS_8;
   public int stopBits=SerialPort.STOPBITS_1;
   public int parity=SerialPort.PARITY_NONE;
   boolean portFound = false;  
   String defaultPort="COM1";  
   static Enumeration portList ;     
   public static  CommPortIdentifier portId;

   public  COMConnect_DLMS()
  {
   initialize();
  }

private void initialize()
{
    System.out.println("Establishing connection to UART");
    portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();  
    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) 
    {  
        portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();  
        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
        {  
            if (portId.getName().equals(defaultPort)) 
            {  
                System.out.println("Found port: "+defaultPort);  
                portFound = true; 
            }
        }
    }
     try 
    {  
     serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleReadApp", 2000);  
    } 
    catch (PortInUseException e) {} 
    System.out.println(portId.getName());

     try
    {
        inputStream=serialPort.getInputStream();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    /*try
    {
        serialPort.addEventListener((SerialPortEventListener) this);
    }
    catch(TooManyListenersException e){}
    serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);*/
    try 
    {  
     // set port parameters  
     serialPort.setSerialPortParams((int) baudRate, dataBits,stopBits,parity);  
    }
    catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {}


    try
    {
        outputStream=serialPort.getOutputStream();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {}
}


 public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event)
 {

    if(event.getEventType()==SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE)
    {
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[20];

        try 
        {
            while (inputStream.available() > 0)
            {
                int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
            }
            System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}

    }
}
public static void writePacket(byte[] msg)
{
   System.out.println("Writing \""+DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(messageString));  
  try 
  {  
    // write string to serial port  
     outputStream.write(msg);  
    //  System.out.println("written");
  } 
  catch (IOException e) {}

}

}
```

And also I want to more about NullPointerException in case of serial ports.Thank you.Your suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: So... *where* is this `NullPointerException` occurring?

Comment: its occuring at the statement :  inputStream=serialPort.getInputStream();

Comment: that is most probably your serialPort variable must be null

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne : can i know why is it coming out to be null? and what wrong i am doing in the above code?

Comment: May be because serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleReadApp", 2000);   throw an exception an still serialPort is null

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is a bit of an issue:

```
try {
    serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleReadApp", 2000);
} catch (PortInUseException e) {
}
```

You've got an empty `catch` block if, for whatever reason, you can't open that specific port.  Worse, you're **not reporting what happened**, or why it decided to fail connecting.

But this is what's breaking you.  You ignore any errors that happen with your `serialPort` variable and leave it set to `null`.  It's initialized this way as a field.

If you fail to get an instance from your call, then you shouldn't continue.  Consider either:

- Placing a `System.exit(1)` call in your `catch` block to indicate that your program cannot continue, or
- (Better option) Wrap ***everything*** in that initialize method that has to do with `serialPort` in your `try...catch`.